# Chrome Not Playing Certain Flash Videos

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1

Why does Chrome not play certain flash videos like the ones on this site? 
http://www.welt.de/sport/fussball/bundesliga/fc-bayern-muenchen/article132052455/Neuer-Bayern-Star-Ehrenmann-oder-Luegner.html 
Clicking on the "Play" icon inside the video does nothing.
Please suggest a fix for this. It works fine on Internet Explorer and Firefox.

My plugins: 
[image: plugins]

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: Nope. Both videos mentioned in the question you linked play normally for me but not the one I have here.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to reproduce. Works fine for me.

I suggest you uninstall Chrome and install the latest new version of Chrome. The uninstall first may delete corrupt files.

[image: video 1] [image: video 2]

Comment: I reinstalled Chrome, it didn't help. I downloaded a portable version and the same. Both are the latest versions too.

Comment: Chrome and the web site may be showing the symptoms, but it sounds like something else is the cause. You have tried rebooting in Safe Mode with Networking and seeing if that allows you to see the videos?

Comment: It doesn't work either in safemode with network. Chrome does nothing, IE crashes and FF plays the video.

Comment: Sounds you got some system issues beyond Chrome nor Flash. Sorry, I do not know. Maybe you can seek some local professional help.